# React adding additional className via props does not follow correct order?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-props

I have a custom component in one file, lets say like that:

```
import styles from './CustomComponent.module.css'

export default CustomComponent = ({className, onClick, text, ...props}) => {
    return (
        <div className={styles.outer}>
            <div className={`${styles.inner} ${className}`}>{text}</div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

That component is imported into another file, which has it's own components and css module:

```
import styles from './ParentComponent.module.css'
import CustomComponent from '../CustomComponent/CustomComponent.component.js'

export default ParentComponent = () => {
    return (
        <>
            This is an example.
            <CustomComponent text='Example' className={styles.overrideStyle} />
        </>
    )
}
```

What I want to happen is that the overrideStyle can be used to add css parameters and/or override some existing ones of the container style. What happens is that new parameters are added, if were not previously defined in the inner style, but already existing ones are not overwritten.

For example, if the CustomComponent css is something like:

```
.outer {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.inner {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

and overrideStyle is something like this:

```
.overrideStyle {
    height: 500px;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

I expected the resulting css properties of the CustomComponent inner div to behave as follows:

```
.(combined) {
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

What I get is:

```
.(combined){
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

New properties are added, but existing ones are not overwritten.

What rules are there that I don't understand and how can I force the className that is passed through props to supersede the inner one?

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your `CustomComponent` it should be

`<div className={`${styles.containerStyle} ${className}`}>{text}</div>`

instead of only `<div className={`${styles.container} ${className}`}>{text}</div>`

Change `styles.container` to `styles.containerStyle` in CustomComponent

Comment: Thanks for the correction, this does not answer my question though.

Comment: That works as expected please check again or be specific what is that you are trying to achieve

Comment: I checked my code again and you were right - the problem only appears for me, when the className is not passed to the outermost div, but to one that is placed inside others. I modified my question to better reflect that and tested this scenario to verify that this problem indeed appears like that.

Answer (score 0):

One fix provided by a friend of mine is to mark the properties of overrideStyle with !important:

```
.overrideStyle {
    height: 500px !important;
    padding: 20px !important;
}
```

This does not solve the problem, but it provides a quick and dirty fix for now.